# Prestashop smarty code

Tags: smarty, prestashop

I want to implement an affiliate platform on my prestashop website.

The tracking code look's like this:

```
http://event.2parale.ro/events/salecheck?

amount=__ADD_SALE_VALUE__&campaign_unique=1f32b97d0&confirm=b51214c259e91116&description=__ADD_DESCRIPTION__&transaction_id=__ADD_TRANSACTION_ID__
```

The problem is that I don't seem to properly replace `__ADD_SALE_VALUE__`, `_ADD_DESCRIPTION__` and `__ADD_TRANSACTION_ID__` with the proper code for the total value of the order, the products sold and the order's id.

Please help.

Regards, 
Sorin

Comment: Can you be a little bit more specific as to how the affiliate mechanism works? It's a little unclear whether the url being built is referring to your site or an external one. Some notes would make it easier to advise properly, such as a list of the steps required and where the above url comes into the equation.

Answer (score 0):

You are using Smarty, right? If so this should do:

In PHP

```
<?php

$smarty->assign('sale_value', 1000);
// ...
$smarty->assign('transaction_id', 123456);
```

Smarty template:

```
amount={$sale_value}&campaign_unique=1f...&transaction_id={$transaction_id}
```